# Cruzamento de Tabelas com Coalesce Múltiplos

Tags: sql-server

Caros,

Eu tenho uma Tabela de "processos solicitados para consulta" e duas tabelas com informações dos processos cadastrados (os processos "novos" e os processos "antigos"). Meu intuito é trazer as informações contidas nos cadastros dos processos para a tabela de processos consultados, em especial a coluna "assunto".

Apesar de ser uma questão simples, a Tabela A possui uma grande falha: alguns processos antigos, que já foram migrados para "processos novos", não aparecem na Tabela A (de consulta), o que me obriga a ter que recorrer para uma "Tabela D", de conversão de processos antigos para os novos, para assim extrair o tão desejado assunto contido na Tabela B. Além disso, minha chave de cruzamento de tabela são dois campos: o ano e número do processo - já que o número do processo pode se repetir em anos diferentes, mas nunca em um mesmo ano.

Exemplificando meu problema:

```
Tabela A (processos consultados)
ano_pcs_novo  nro_pcs_novo   pcs_antigo   outras_A 
A             a              NULL         X
B             b              NULL         X
NULL          NULL           AAA          X
NULL          NULL           BBB          X
C             c              NULL         X
A             a              NULL         X
NULL          NULL           DDD          X

Tabela B (cadastro dos processos novos)
ano_pcs_novo  nro_pcs_novo   assunto  outras_B
A             a              1        Y
B             b              2        Y       
C             c              3        Y
D             d              4        Y
E             e              5        Y
F             f              6        Y

Tabela C (cadastro dos processos antigos)
pcs_antigo   outras_C
AAA          Z
BBB          Z
CCC          Z
DDD          Z  

Tabela D (conversão de processos antigos para novos)
pcs_antigo  ano_pcs_novo  nro_pcs_novo
AAA         A             a
BBB         B             b
CCC         C             c
DDD         D             d
```

Eu desejo:

```
Tabela A
ano_pcs_novo  nro_pcs_novo  pcs_antigo assunto outras_A outras_B outras_C
A             a             NULL       1       X         Y         Z
B             b             NULL       2       X         Y         Z
A             a             AAA        1       X         Y         Z
B             b             BBB        2       X         Y         Z
C             c             NULL       3       X         Y         Z
A             a             NULL       1       X         Y         Z
D             d             DDD        4       X         Y         Z
```

Observações:
Na Tabela A os campos de processos consultados se repetem.
Na Tabela B, C e D os campos são únicos. Nem todos os processos antigos foram convertidos.

Como posso proceder? Com ajuda da comunidade, o mais próximo que cheguei envolveu o uso de Select Distinct, Coalesce e Left Join, mas como minha principal chave aqui são duas colunas (ano_pcs_novo e nro_pcs_novo) não consegui ir além. Imagino que tenha que usar concatenar, mas não consegui efetuar a consulta de forma apropriada.

Comment: A tabela D possui linhas para todos os processos antigos?

Comment: Não tem, mas a maioria está convertida. Mas não é 1:1 neste caso.

Comment: complicou um pouco mais q ontem né amigo...rsrs coloque o código que já está utilizando rsrs

Comment: Pois é, notei que a pergunta de ontem não transparecia todo o problema...

Comment: se puder, coloca no SQLFiddle, ajuda muito

Comment: @YuriCamaraBatista: não há colunas de conteúdo comum nas tabelas B e C, sendo que então o conteúdo teria ou que vir de B ou de C? Por exemplo, existindo a coluna nomeRequerente no processo, tanto na forma antiga como na nova, na tabela A deve ser colocado ou o conteúdo da tabela B (caso seja um processo novo) ou da tabela C (caso seja um processo antigo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

veja se resolve seu problema:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Coalesce(A.ano_pcs_novo,D.ano_pcs_novo) as ano_pcs_novo,
Coalesce(A.nro_pcs_novo,D.nro_pcs_novo) as nro_pcs_novo,
A.pcs_antigo,
B.assunto,
A.outras_A,
B.outras_B,
C.outras_C
FROM A

LEFT OUTER JOIN D on D.pcs_antigo = A.pcs_antigo 
                  or (D.ano_pcs_novo = A.ano_pcs_novo  
                      and D.nro_pcs_novo = A.nro_pcs_novo)
LEFT OUTER JOIN B on B.ano_pcs_novo = D.ano_pcs_novo 
                      and B.nro_pcs_novo = D.nro_pcs_novo
LEFT OUTER JOIN C on C.pcs_antigo = D.pcs_antigo
```

Comment: fiz alguns acertos e editei a resposta.

Comment: por enquanto a sua funcionou. Estou fazendo checagem com outras planilhas para ver se o cruzamento deu certo. Já dou o retorno

Comment: Deu certíssimo Rovann! Agora sim, obrigado!

Comment: certo, disponha =]

Comment: @YuriCamaraBatista se puder atualize a tabela que você colocou como desejo de resposta na sua pergunta. Ela contém registros duplicados por ano/nro do processo novo, que da um entendimento que o resultado acompanhe os registros da tabela A e não da tabela B onde esses campos são únicos..

Comment: @Pagotti os resultados acompanham os registros da tabela A sim, porém nos resultados desejados, onde na tabela A tem apenas o `pcs_antigo` tem que aparecer `ano_pcs_novo` e `nro_pcs_novo` o inverso não é necessário. Assim, não são registros duplicados, mas apenas que houve várias consultas para um mesmo processo

Comment: @RovannLinhalis O que eu notei é que o resultado desse SQL não bate com o resultado que ele apresentou na pergunta. Por exemplo, na tabela A tem duas vezes o ano = 'A' e nro = 'a' e isso repete no resultado esperado por ele. Porém o resultado desse SQL aparece apenas uma vez por conta do DISTINCT.

Comment: entendi, mas acredito que ele deve ter outras colunas não mostradas na estrutura dele, como data/hora e codigo da consulta, o que faria trazer o resultado desejado a ele, mesmo com o distinct.

Comment: @Pagotti É exatamente isso. Como é uma tabela de processos consultados há repetição das informações. Infelizmente, o registro dos dados é ruim, e há usuários que registram processos já migrados como processos antigos, fazendo com que processos (como no exemplo o Aa e o Bb) tenham registros tanto como um processo novo como antigo. É basicamente essa a razão de eu ter precisado de ajuda, caso contrário eu não precisaria fazer tantos cruzamentos.

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma sugestão inicial:

```
-- código #1 v4
SELECT coalesce(A.ano_pcs_novo, D.ano_pcs_novo) as ano_pcs_novo,
       coalesce(A.nro_pcs_novo, D.nro_pcs_novo) as nro_pcs_novo,
       A.pcs_antigo,
       B.assunto, A.outras_A, B.outras_B, C.outras_C
       --,case when A.pcs_antigo is null then B.outras_x else C.outras_x end as outras_x
       --,case when A.pcs_antigo is null then B.outras_y else C.outras_y end as outras_y
       --,case when A.pcs_antigo is null then B.outras_z else C.outras_z end as outras_z
  from TabelaA as A
       left join TabelaB as B on B.ano_pcs_novo = A.ano_pcs_novo
                                 and B.nro_pcs_novo = A.nro_pcs_novo
       left join TabelaC as C on C.pcs_antigo = A.pcs_antigo
       left join TabelaD as D on D.pcs_antigo = A.pcs_antigo;
go
```

No código acima, as colunas outras_x, outras_y e outras_z referem-se a informações em comum às tabelas B e C e que tem que vir ou da tabela B ou da tabela C (dependendo se é um processo novo ou antigo). Por exemplo, existindo a coluna nomeRequerente no processo, tanto na forma antiga como na nova, na tabela A deve ser colocado ou o conteúdo da tabela B (caso seja um processo novo) ou da tabela C (caso seja um processo antigo).

Comment: Assunto não vem da tabela `C`, apenas de `B`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: Estou aguardando uma resposta do Yuri. É que, em se tratando de processos, me parece que há conteúdo em comum entre as duas tabelas (processos antigos e novos).

Answer (score 1):

Pela estrutura que você apresentou, me parece que a saída desejada é algo como isso:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(A.ano_pcs_novo, D.ano_pcs_novo) AS ano_pcs_novo, 
  COALESCE(A.nro_pcs_novo, D.nro_pcs_novo) AS nro_pcs_novo, A.pcs_antigo, 
  COALESCE(B.assunto, B1.assunto), A.outras_A, 
  COALESCE(B.outras_B, B1.outras_B), 
  COALESCE(C.outras_C, C1.outras_C)
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN C ON A.pcs_antigo = C.pcs_antigo
  LEFT JOIN D ON D.pcs_antigo = C.pcs_antigo
  LEFT JOIN B AS B1 ON D.ano_pcs_novo = B1.ano_pcs_novo AND D.nro_pcs_novo = B1.nro_pcs_novo
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.ano_pcs_novo = B.ano_pcs_novo AND A.nro_pcs_novo = B.nro_pcs_novo
  LEFT JOIN D AS D1 ON D1.ano_pcs_novo = A.ano_pcs_novo AND D1.nro_pcs_novo = A.nro_pcs_novo
  LEFT JOIN C AS C1 ON D1.pcs_antigo = C1.pcs_antigo
```

Aqui tem um [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9bYkayp6cHwBegKtmq2nqr/2) para testar essa hipótese. Eu criei um ID a mais nesse Fiddle em A para que o resultado viesse na ordem correta.

Comment: Que bom que você fez a simulação dos dados!  _rs_  Usei o SQL Fiddle para testar e descobri que tinha um erro de escrita no código que propus. Grato.

Comment: @JoséDiz descobri há pouco tempo esse DB-Fiddle